# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata' in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, error-handling, runtime-error

```
Launching lib\main.dart on STK LX1 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
        Dependency: androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
        AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Marwa\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\625039eaad011f884ddd84f857a44b7f\jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
        Dependency: androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04.
        AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Marwa\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a78fdf90e4c1f8464b19895cfb365f3f\jetified-window-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 59s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 5):

in your project, go to android/app/build.gradle

in:

android{

make sure your
compileSdkVersion  is set to 31 :

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 31
.
.
.
.
}
```